# Can you have keyword arguments without supplying a default value?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am used to having function/method definitions like so in Python:

```
def my_function(arg1=None , arg2='default'):
    ... do stuff here
```

If I don't supply `arg1` (or `arg2`), then the default value of `None` (or `'default'`) is assigned.

Can I specify keyword arguments like this, but without a default value? I would expect it to raise an error if the argument was not supplied.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can in modern Python (3, that is):

```
>>> def func(*, name1, name2):
...     print(name1, name2)
...     
>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-08a2da4138f6>", line 1, in <module>
    func()
TypeError: func() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'name1' and 'name2'    
>>> func("Fred", "Bob")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-7-14386ea74437>", line 1, in <module>
    func("Fred", "Bob")
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

>>> func(name1="Fred", name2="Bob")
Fred Bob
```

Comment: its not quite a drop-in replacement because `func("fred", "bob")` does work with standard keyword arguments.

Comment: Its Python 2.7 I am using.

Comment: Likewise, if you want to specify positional arguments and accept more keyword arguments, you can write: `def func(*args, name1, name2, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Because of what says tdelaney, I think the solution given by Dolda2000 is relevant i.e. "Any argument can be given as with a keyword expression, whether or not it has a default"

Answer (score 24):

Any argument can be given as with a keyword expression, whether or not it has a default:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a - b
foo(2, 1)         # Returns 1
foo(a=2, b=1)     # Returns 1
foo(b=2, a=1)     # Returns -1
foo()             # Raises an error
```

If you want to force the arguments to be keyword-*only*, then see DSM's answer, but that didn't seem like what you were really asking.

Answer (score -1):

you can specify your keyword arguments without default value as follows:
`def(*,**name1, **name2): print(name1, name2)`