# How to use unquoted keyword-only function args in Python

Tags: python-3.x

It is easy to create optional arguments in a function by specifying a default in the def.

for example `sorted([1,3,2],reverse=True)`

if I were defining this function I might say

```
def sorted(l:list, reverse:bool=False)
```

is there any way to define a function's parameters so that I can specify keywords without values? Simply mentioning the keyword makes it true. If there were I could define a function that accepts this

`sorted([1,3,2],reverse)`

I tried using **kwargs but apparently, it only accepts keywords that are included with values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you have keyword arguments without supplying a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037146/can-you-have-keyword-arguments-without-supplying-a-default-value)

Comment: @Tzane it does not. It describes keyword arguments with = sign and value. I was asking for keyword arguments without the "=value" as in the unquoted "reverse") in  sorted([1,3,2],reverse)

Comment: Assuming you have previously assigned a value to `reverse`, `sorted([1,3,2],reverse)` should be valid code. Are trying figure out how to provide the function an undefined variable and if it's not use the default instead?

Comment: @Tzane thanks ... that is basic Python, but not what I was asking about. I was looking for a way to use the symbol reverse rather than use it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to what I was looking for would be to use an Enum

```
import enum

class SortDirection(enum.Enum):
    REGULAR = None
    REVERSE = 2

def sorted(l:list, reverse:SortDirection=None):
    print(reverse)

sorted([], SortDirection.REVERSE)
```

So the above program outputs

```
SortDirection.REVERSE
```